# Regex match either word, but the exact word

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

i'm struggling figure out a regex. I want to replace a space with a dash but only if the following word matches either `class` or `series`.

I have tried the following:

```
/\s(?=[^\s]*(class|series)$)/gi

'  E-Class' => ' -E-Class'
'E Class'   => 'E-Class'
' E Class'  => ' E-Class'
```

Above is close, but if there is already a dash it puts one before, which it shouldn't.

Comment: for the first case of `'  E-Class' => ' -E-Class'`shouldn't the requirement change then from *"... replace a space with a dash but only if the following word matches ..."* TO *"... replace a space with a dash but only if the following word **contains** ..."*

Comment: Regarding all the answers / solutions / approaches are there any questions left?

Comment: @PeterSeliger Just marked my answer as the solution as it works perfect for my use case. Thanks for the help from other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out, this works as expected:

`/\s(?=class|series)/gi`

Answer (score 1):

Following regex/approach matches the criteria described by the OP ...

[`/\s(?=class|series)|\s(\w+-?)+(?=class|series)/gi`](https://regex101.com/r/xAFOF0/1).

Actually it's two separate regular expressions, one (`\s(?=class|series)`) for the obviously simple case of matching the pattern of e.g. `' E Class'`, the other one (`\s(\w+-?)+(?=class|series)`) for the more complex patterns such as e.g. `'  E-Class'` or `'  Ee-ef-fooSeries'` where the OP wants to *"... replace a space with a dash but only if the following word **[contains]** either `class` or `series`"* (*contains* and **not** *matches*; see my first comment above).

The regex' match result needs to be handled by a custom replacer function. A test case might look similar to the next provided one ...

```js
const testEntries = [

  // OP's request.
  ['  E-Class', ' -E-Class'],
  ['E Class', 'E-Class'],
  [' E Class', ' E-Class'],

  // Bonus test.
  ['  Ee-eClass', ' -Ee-eClass'],
  [' Ee-ef-Class', '-Ee-ef-Class'],
  ['  Ee-ef-fooSeries', ' -Ee-ef-fooSeries'],
];
const regX = (/\s(?=class|series)|\s(\w+-?)+(?=class|series)/gi);

function didPassTest([value, expectedValue]) {
  return (
    value.replace(regX, (match) =>
      '-' + match.trim()
    ) === expectedValue
  );
} 
console.log(
  'testEntries.every(didPassTest) ?..',
  testEntries.every(didPassTest)
);
```

One can unify the above `OR` based regex literal into a version which matches the overall pattern while capturing the word ...

[`/\s((?:\w+-?)*(?:class|series))/gi`](https://regex101.com/r/xAFOF0/2)

The above example code then changes to ...

```js
const testEntries = [

  // OP's request.
  ['  E-Class', ' -E-Class'],
  ['E Class', 'E-Class'],
  [' E Class', ' E-Class'],

  // Bonus test.
  ['  Ee-eClass', ' -Ee-eClass'],
  [' Ee-ef-Class', '-Ee-ef-Class'],
  ['  Ee-ef-fooSeries', ' -Ee-ef-fooSeries'],
];
const regX = (/\s((?:\w+-?)*(?:class|series))/gi);

function didPassTest([value, expectedValue]) {
  return (value.replace(

    regX, (match, word) => '-' + word

  ) === expectedValue);
} 
console.log(
  'testEntries.every(didPassTest) ?..',
  testEntries.every(didPassTest)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should only match the space before class or series and not every space before so you can try something like this :

```
/\s(class|series)$/gi
```

Comment: That isn't matching the space at all

Comment: my bad I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `[^\s]*` (No-Spaces) inside your positive look ahead, every word which ends in `class` or `series` (like `E-Class` or `abcdefclass`) matches your positive look ahead. If you only want to replace the space in front of `class` and `series` you can simply remove that and use `/\s(?=(class|series)$)/gi`